# android api gesture emulation from gesture to gesture

Tags: android

here is my problem
I want to emulate the gesture in this way:
for example, I tap the screen top left, but android thinks, that I tap bottom right.
I have a Wrapper class, where I override the method dispatchTouchEvent. There I can intercept the gesture and give the super.dispatchTouchEvent new MotionEvent. But how can I give the MotionEvent new coordinates of gesture? The object MotionEvent has no setters for X and Y

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simulate motion events in `Android` and forward them to the system. This would be a serious security flaw and this is exactly why the `MotionEvent` class does not have public constructors and

> The object MotionEvent has no setters for X and Y